# MYOB - task automation

Tags: automation, autoit, myob

Is there any tool that can automate exporting all reports from MYOB (AccountRight Plus)?
I've tried AutoIt and Sikuli but it seems that mouse clicks (and keyboard send/type commands) are somehow ignored. Is it  possible?
Below is the AutoIt script I'm using:

```
    #include <ImageSearch.au3>
    #include <WinAPI.au3>
    #include <Constants.au3>
    $x1=0
    $y1=0
    WinActivate("AccountRight Plus")
    Sleep(200)
    $result = _ImageSearch("Accounts.bmp",1,$x1,$y1,0)
    if $result=1 Then
        MouseMove($x1,$y1,3)
        MouseClick("left")
        Sleep(1000)
        MouseClick("left")
        $aMouse = MouseGetPos() ; Remembers current mouse position
        ConsoleWrite("Mouse Clicked at " & $aMouse[0] & "," & $aMouse[1] & @LF)
        Sleep(500)
        ;Try with Handle
        Local $handle = WinGetHandle("AccountRight Plus")
        If @error Then
            MsgBox(4096, "Error", "Could not find the correct window")
        Else
            ConsoleWrite("$handle = " & $handle & @LF)
            ControlSend($handle, "", "", "^i")
        EndIf
        Sleep(1000)
        ;try winAPI
        ;MsgBox(0, "Info", "Moving mouse")
        _WinAPI_Mouse_Event($MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 653, 454)
        _WinAPI_Mouse_Event($MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN)
        Sleep(500)
        _WinAPI_Mouse_Event($MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP)
        ; try Control Click
        $controResult=ControlClick("ABC - Command Centre",20806,"left",2,62,106)
        ConsoleWrite("controlResult = " & $controResult & @LF)
        Sleep(1000)
        ; try ControSend to inner frame
        $controResult=ControlSend("AccountRight Plus","ABC- Command Centre",20806,"{TAB}")
        ConsoleWrite("controlResult = " & $controResult & @LF)
        Sleep(1000)
        ; try ControSend to outer frame
        $controResult=ControlSend("AccountRight Plus","","","{ALT}")
        ConsoleWrite("controlResult = " & $controResult & @LF)
        Sleep(1000)
        ; try with CLASS
        $controResult=ControlSend("AccountRight Plus","","[CLASS:MDIClient; INSTANCE:1]","{TAB}")
        ConsoleWrite("controlResult = " & $controResult & @LF)
        Sleep(1000)
        ; try send
        Send("{TAB}")
        Sleep(1000)
        Send("{TAB}")
        Sleep(1000)
        ;try MenuSelect
        WinMenuSelectItem("AccountRight Plus", "", "&File")
        Sleep(1000)
        MsgBox(0,"Found","picture found.")
            EndIf
```

Comment: What and HOW have you done so far? I am surprised because AutoIt (like autoHotKey) simulates keystrokes and mouse clicks just like a user would do. Is this web-based or a downloaded app? Do you check that the right window is open before executing commands. Do you execute mouse commands based on x-y coordinates or based on button-ID's (if x-y coordinates are the buttons on the same place or do you search for the button images). Do you allow time between the commands (sleep, xx) or just execute in one big swoop?

Comment: Thanks for this.
MYOB is an old desktop app. I can bring it to focus but then all keystrokes send using AutoIt are ignored. I tried AHK and WSH but get the same results (none). I do use sleep between commands.
I'll update the question with the script that I'm using.
Thanks again

Comment: When you read this note:  http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/59695-myob-software-automation/  It seems that the old MYOB program is reading the low level keyboard scancodes directly, thus ignoring programs like autoHotKey.

Comment: I have not yet checked your code, but one thing that seems to be strange is: Send("{TAB}"), I was expecting Send, {TAB}. One question do you have ANY keys or mouse actions that AHK can send to MYOB? If nothing worked so far, then you should focus on getting a working send and a working mouseclick first and work from there.

Comment: thanks!.
I tried AHK with simple send but it didn't work. The script brings MYOB to focus but then al send command are ignored.
I also tried the two scripts in the thread mentioned above.

Comment: thanks!.
I tried AHK with simple send but it didn't work. The script brings MYOB to focus but then all send command are ignored.
I also tried the two scripts in the thread mentioned above. In both cases if MYOB is active (Focused) two web help pages open. If MYOB not is not active, I get the msgBox.
Any recommendations for next steps?

Comment: As said it looks like MYOB read the scancodes directly. You could try SendPlay, but I doubt that this works. There are some threads about games that behave the same way and I did not see any good resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Nushi,,

Have you tried to use the scan codes directly in your application?

Here is an example. It clicks the mouse at the current location and then sends a {Tab}. You need to change this for your needs. You can move your mouse to the right location first with "MouseMove,150,250" these are the X,Y locations.

```
F8:: ; Press F8 to start macro
Send, {vk01} ; Click left mouse button
;Send, {scYYY} ; 
Send, {vk09sc00F} ; Send the Vk and SC codes for the {Tab} key.
Return
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: Can you let me know if using the VK or SC codes did solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working...
What could possibly be the reason?
Thank you so much for trying to help!

Comment: Nushi, I created a script with only two actions, one mouse and one keyboard. If you comment out the tab line (4) and place the mouse over a MYOB button and press F8, nothing happens? or if you comment out the mouse click line (2) and use the tab line when you are inside an area where you can tab back and forth, nothing happens either?

Comment: Correct. Nothing happens in these two scenarios. The only things I managed to do so far is to activate (bring to focus) the window, find an image (with AutoIt) and move the mouse (with AutoIt but not always works).
Thanks again,
Nushi